# Using same script with different input over same html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im trying to make a JavaScript to use the same code over different parts of an html code, the script read the title, runtime and plot from a specific url request and should place that information inside the correct div. How can i do this?

```
<div>
  <input id="img1" type="radio" name="img-descr">
     <div id="tt0110912"> <!-- Pulp fiction -->
         <h1 id="Title"></h1>
         <p id="Runtime"></p>
         <p id="Plot"></p>
     </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="img2" type="radio" name="img-descr">
     <div id="tt0796366"> <!-- Star Trek -->
         <h1 id="Title"></h1>
         <p id="Runtime"></p>
         <p id="Plot"></p>
     </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="img3" type="radio" name="img-descr">
     <div id="tt0251413"> <!-- Star Wars -->
         <h1 id="Title"></h1>
         <p id="Runtime"></p>
         <p id="Plot"></p>
     </div>
</div>

<!-- Script para la api de OMDB -->    

<script>            
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var fullMovie = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var movie = { title: fullMovie.Title, runtime: fullMovie.Runtime, plot: fullMovie.Plot, };
            document.getElementById('Title').innerText = movie.title;
            document.getElementById('Runtime').innerText = movie.runtime;
            document.getElementById('Plot').innerText = movie.plot
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'variable?', true);
    xhr.send(null);
</script>
```

The following url is called for each movie:

```
http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0110912&plot=short&r=json  (Pulp Fiction Movie)
http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0796366&plot=short&r=json  (Star Trek Movie)
http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0251413&plot=short&r=json  (Star Wars Movie)
```

How can i add an id to the div with the correct ?i=tt******* information so the script add the correct answer to the title, runtime and plot section?

Thinking on it the script should, read the div id, use that id to fetch the information:

```
var search = document.getElementById('dividhere').value;
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=+search+&plot=short&r=json', true);
xhr.send();
}
```

The script should read the  and run the xhr.open with that id information, place the information fetched inside that div and run the script on the second div, and again on the third div. So if i add another div with a new id information the script will load for the new movie.

Comment: you do realize that you've put `<!-- Script para la api de OMDB -->` right in JavaScript?

Comment: ill correct this, ty!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, using JQuery (please use it). First, add class to your div :

```
<div class="movie" id="tt0796366"> <!-- Star Trek -->
```

Then :

```
$('.movie').each(function(i, item) {
    $.getJSON('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i='+ $(this).attr('id') +'&plot=short&r=json', function(data) {
       $(item).find('h1').html(data.title);
       ....
   });
});
```

Comment: where do i put that? and how do i make each div to read that?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand your problem ? Firstly, I think you should use Jquery to make your code more easy. Then, explain me ..

Comment: There are 3 main div sections, for 3 movies. I need to run the script on each div and load the title, runtime and plot information from each movie. using just one script so i can in a future, add more movie div's.

Comment: Look my answer, using JQuery.

Comment: I cant use Jquery, just JavaScript

Comment: Samething in Javascript. Loop through your elements, call XHR everytime. But use JQuery...

Comment: I have the following code, but i need to load the information for each image. https://jsfiddle.net/yx37Ljzm/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can render your HTML dynamically using your JS, like this (https://jsfiddle.net/6usmu7ny/1/):

JavaScript

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('[name="img-descr"]');
var loaded = [];

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        renderMovie(evt.target.nextElementSibling)
      }, false);
}

function renderMovie(el) {
    var movie = el.id

    if(loaded.indexOf(movie) !== -1) return;

    loaded.push(movie);

    getMovieInformation(movie, function(data) {
        var title = document.createTextNode(data.Title);
        var runtime = document.createTextNode(data.Runtime);
        var plot = document.createTextNode(data.Plot);

        el.querySelector('#Title').appendChild(title);
        el.querySelector('#Runtime').appendChild(runtime);
        el.querySelector('#Plot').appendChild(plot);
    }); 
};

function getMovieInformation(movie, cb) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var fullMovie = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            cb(fullMovie);
        }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?i='+movie+'&plot=short&r=json');
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: i cant do it this way beacuse the input information is already in the html structure, when i click over an img, the input will be showed with the movie information.

Comment: i want the script to read <div id="tt0796366"> and run the xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=+search+&plot=short&r=json', true); (replacing +search+ with the div id. Place the information returned inside that div.

Comment: I have the following code, over each image i need to load the OMDB api information: jsfiddle.net/yx37Ljzm/1 i hope you can understand what is my problem. I need to use the same script which is working with only one title, make a function so that script is used over and over